# MySQL Domo AWS RDS Connector

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, ssl, domo

I'm having issues connecting Domo to a MySQL database hosted with AWS RDS. Whenever I try to authenticate I get this error:

"Failed to authenticate. Verify the credentials and try again. Domo is ready, but the credentials you entered are invalid. Verify your account credentials and try again. Error setting up SQL connection. Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."

Its not security group settings. Someone suggested on this post:
https://dojo.domo.com/t5/Data-Sources-and-Connectors/MySQL-connector-issues/td-p/15462

that I should enable SSL in AWS database but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using the MySQL connector, not the MySQL SSH connector.

It sounds like you need to whitelist Domo's IP addresses within your AWS RDS's security groups.

Aside from that, make sure you're populating the credentials in Domo with the right pieces of information. Hostname should be the server's public IP address.

This connector follows the same general process as described in AWS's [documentation here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-ssh-workbench-connect-ec2/), with the exception that steps 5 and 6 are optional since SSH is not required for this connector.